# Differentiate between two Xcode targets with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How can I differentiate between two Xcode targets with Swift? The idea is to make a free and a paid version of an app with the same code base in Xcode.

With objective C I could use preprocessor macros but with Swift those are unavailable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since Xcode 8 you can set the compilation conditions in the Build Settings for each target under **Active Compilation Conditions**.

[image: Active Compilation Conditions Screenshot]

With those set you can use:

```
#if FREE
   //do something
#endif
```

For more details see the [i40west answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284418/1356575) and comments.

Answer (score 47):

In Xcode, go into the build configuration for a target. Find the section called **Swift Compiler - Custom Flags**, which contains a setting called **Other Swift Flags**.

Add a command-line flag for the compiler to add a flag, pretty much just like you’d do with the C compiler.

[image: Swift Compiler Flags]

Now you’ve got `-D Something` being passed to the Swift compiler. In your Swift code, you can now do this:

```
#if Something
    let foo = "bar"
#endif
```

It looks a lot like the C preprocessor, but unlike C, all code in all conditional sections has to be syntactically correct or the program won’t compile. So, you can set a flag on each target in the build settings and use them in your code.

Comment: More importantly, all code in an `#if`, active or no, must also be a *complete* syntactic unit. So you can't, say, put an `#if/#else/#endif` around just a `func` declaration and leave the function body outside the `#if`.

Comment: is this work in storyboard ,,I want to change image based on target in storyboard

Comment: I don't get it. shouldn't it be `if Something == QA` else if Something == Stage`... The way you wrote it, it seems that the **existence** of that flag is all that's necessary. What would happen if two builds have the same flag?!

Comment: If you need to test multiple values, then yes. This is just a straight boolean.

Comment: Is this will work if I need to include a resource [either a swift file or nib] in one target and not in others.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to add Flags to target and use preprocessor. But the other way I think would be to use something like this

```
if Bundle.appTarget == "" { } else { }


extension Bundle {

    public static var appVersion: String? {
        return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String
    }

    public static var appBuild: String? {
        return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleVersionKey as String) as? String
    }

    public static func _version() -> String {
        let dictionary = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!
        let version = dictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
        let build = dictionary["CFBundleVersion"] as! String
        return "\(version) build \(build)"
    }

    public static var appTarget: String? {
        if let targetName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleExecutable") as? String {
            return targetName
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use  Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName")

this keys should be defined in Info.plist