# IOS Targets for each client

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

**A little background:**

In android we have developed the same app, basically we have developed the Android app first now we have created its IOS version, so there are multiple clients of this app. In android we are really handling this situation using Android modules system.

Now in IOS we have to do same thing. And that is to make the samecode base to be use in for multiple clients.

I did research and found the Targets and framework are the best option. I created the workspace added the framework and added the projects. But it all going in trouble for no reason.

So I decided to move onto targets. So I read and its easy to understand but can it satisfy my following requirements

1. Separate swift file for each target. (I have a common file which contains URL links and other things, that is needed different for each client, so can I make same file per client having change the urls and other things
2. App icons (there must be separate icons for each targets )
3. Colors off app (I want different color for each client. Here I really do not know how to do this, because I have given Colors to app using IB)
4. FCM and its file "GoogleService-Info.plist" (how it should be managed for multiple targets )

Update: This is How I am coding in App Delegate

```
    import Firebase
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]
        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]
        return true
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

Please tell is it achievable using "Targets" and how?

Comment: It is `iOS` and not `IOS`. IOS is a term used by Cisco. And yes, targets is the right way to do this.

Comment: @adev thanks, Iwill be carefull next time

Answer (score 2):

**1.** When you create target all files added till then will be available to the newly created target. Then for every new file you add you can choose the target for that file. You can change that preference in target membership section in file inspector.

**2.** You can have different app icon for different targets

1. Create a different app icon in Assets
2. Then set the newly created app icon in target -> App icon section.

   [image]

   [image]

**3.** For different color:

You can set compile flags for each target

Locate Swift compiler flags in the target build settings under Swift Compiler — Custom Flags → Other Swift Flags

[image]

Created flag in other swift flags will help to distinguish between the target.
Then Depending upon the value give color like this

```
#if TARGET1

let fillColor       = UIColor(red: 30/255.0, green: 100/255.0, blue: 100/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let fillColorWithAlpha  = UIColor(red: 30/255.0, green: 100/255.0, blue: 100/255.0, alpha: 0.9)

let buttonColor     = UIColor(red: 15/255.0, green: 45/255.0, blue: 90/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let buttonColorDeselected = UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 100/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1.0)



#else
let fillColor       = UIColor(red: 74/255.0, green: 144/255.0, blue: 226/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let fillColorWithAlpha       = UIColor(red: 74/255.0, green: 144/255.0, blue: 226/255.0, alpha: 0.9)

let buttonColor     = UIColor(red: 36/255.0, green: 97/255.0, blue: 168/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let buttonColorDeselected = UIColor(red: 116/255, green: 116/255, blue: 116/255, alpha: 1.0)



#endif
```

Where "TARGET1" is the value you have given in swift flag section.

Lastly Use this fillColor that you configured to change the Color. For Example to set background color of UIButton to that color -> Create custom class and give the color that you have configured for different target. By doing this you can just change the color in configuration rather than updating the entire UI

```
class CustomThemeButton: UIButton {


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setBackGroundColor()
    }

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setBackGroundColor()
    }

    private func setBackGroundColor(){

        self.backgroundColor = fillColor
    }

}
```

Comment: how about FCM plist file created by Google? how to add multiple file per client vise, (as per client/target I will change its package name)

Comment: Each target you create will have its own info.plist file where you will set bundle id. And you can add different google plist , each google plist will be associated to particular bundle id.

Comment: @Androidteem I think at time of adding google plist, you can specify the target.

Comment: ok, but still I am unable to understand this "First create flag in other swift flags to distingush between the target. Then Depending upon the value give color like this" and the file you shown as example , you did not tell me where to add and how to deal

Comment: please feel free to consider me iOS dumb

Comment: @Androidteem. I have edited the answer, please take a look.

Comment: Refer this for more details:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284418/6818278

Comment: can u check and tell how to associate google.plist file with each target. I have added one and checked the target 2

Comment: now what ?...... when I will install target 2 app, will it itself pick target2  google.plist file??

Comment: Yes.. At the time of adding plist you can choose the corresponding target for that plist file.

Comment: yes, did the same, but after adding a new target and added a new images and every thing I needed, it was working just fine . But as I added the google.plist 2nd file for the target , the fcm stopped working though . No notification recvied

Comment: Do you need to add any code  while setting up of fcm ? I guess you will require some Service Key that you have give while configuring .. How is that done ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176625/discussion-between-anuraj-and-android-teem).

Comment: yes when I add next google Json File and select target and build successfully on 2 different device using different targets for each, FCM stops working