# How to create multiple apps at once using same code using swift

Tags: ios

We are developing a `custom app`(food delivery app for different restaurants). It is the same app written once with a set of `templates`,`fonts` etc where clients can chooose a template they like in website and set it and need their app to look the same.It is similar to `Chow Now`. So I would like to know how to code once and use it for every app with little modifications like AppIcon(getting it from URL) and `publish the build to App Store from website`.

Any suggestions/ideas would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

In order to publish the same codebase with some little changes, you will have to change the

> bundle identifier

for your app, then you could reuse the same code.

Comment: bundle identifier should be changed by us (developers). But we are looking for something where there is no need for a developer to change the bundleid each time for some 1000 restaurants and publish the app. The Client itself want to create their app by using templates already designed in website(those templates selected in website will be applied in app) and create app and publish to store.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple Targets in the same code base and with different bundle IDs.

This will help you with different project settings as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following solution.

1. You can make use of different **Target** for different App.
   [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51491809/6818278)
2. You can create different repo for different project.

   **Note that** you will have to change the code in each repo for reflecting the change in each project.